# Intersection Observer triggering callback twice on ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, intersection-observer

I tried to lazy load images using Intersection Observable in my angular 7 application. I called Intersection Observable from ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook. But when i load the application, callback is called twice, once with all the isIntersecting values as true and the next one with the correct isIntersecting values. I am confused with this behaviour.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
const imgOne = document.querySelectorAll('[data-class]');

    const options = {
      // root: document
      // threshold: 0
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
      console.log(entries.length);
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        // console.log(entry);
        if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
          return;
        } else {
          const el = entry.target;
          if (el.id === ('test' + this.testCount)) {
            console.log(entry);
          }
          // observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
      });
    });

    imgOne.forEach((eachQuery) => {
      observer.observe(eachQuery);
    });
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqbuyr

UPDATE : Now intersection observer is called perfectly, but now a issue occured. Since we are using document.querySelectorAll which returns a static node list, once the array is updted node list is not updated. If i try to use document.getElementsByClassName, an error throws as it is not an Node list ???

Comment: Have you tried by this way ```observer.observe(imgOne);```, no need foreach.

Comment: Use the class into queryselector not the data attribute ```observer.observe(document.querySelectorAll('img.lzy_img'));```

Comment: It will thrown an error - 'Argument of type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.'    as observe gets a single element as its argument not an array of elements.

Comment: Please create the example to stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqbuyr

Comment: Now i have made it to work, but now the issue once i increase the count of the array,  observer is not taking the new array ???

Comment: I solved the issue by removing ngOnInit(), as it was triggering ngAfterViewInit() again after loading.

Comment: Very interesting, your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing ngOnInit(), as it was triggering ngAfterViewInit() again after loading.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this also works:

```js
if (entry.isIntersecting && Math.floor(entry.intersectionRatio) === 1) { 
  const el = entry.target;
  if (el.id === ('test' + this.testCount)) {
    console.log(entry);
  }
} else {
  return;
}
```

"*If you dont' check intersectionRatio ratio === 1, the observed element will trigger the callback twice, because when immediately passing/leaving 100% threshold, observer will trigger isIntersecting = true, intersectionRatio ~= 0.9 (maybe bug).
Chrome somehow gets intersectionRatio slightly above 1 on the first box, so floor the value*"

Source: https://codepen.io/mmanney/details/erpZbd